# Installing X509 certificate on SmartCard / into a CSP

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, cryptography, x509

I have a .p12 file - I'm trying to install the cert on a smart card.  I have a CSP installed and can instantiate a valid `CspParameters` object for an `RSACryptoServiceProvider` for example.  But how can I import the cert?

I know I can read certs from the card using the local `X509Store`, but how can I write them?

Comment: **Depends on the card** - normally you cannot just import certificates into a card. Key generation and certificate import is normally done during personalization of the card. Most card are read only when in the field; the only thing you can do is to read out the certificates and use (not export) the private key. Note that installing a certificate is normally not an issue, installing a private key **is**. Even though .NET mixes those two terms together, they are rather different if only because one of them is public information, and the other should be kept private.

Comment: `certutil -importpfx` with a `-csp` parameter works, so I'm using an API spy tool and following the method used there.  Looks pretty promising so far.. get private key data from cert, then install in new key container in target CSP.  Why would it be any different to that?

Comment: The issue is that there is no such thing as a standard that every smart card complies to. So if the card was created for such a use case, it may just work. Then again, many cards are put in the field read only, or they only allow private keys that are generated in the card, or they are not even fully programmed yet (e.g. I specialize in Java Card). There are a few reasons why it could work, and there are tens of reasons why it would not...